# Proving that determinants of matrices are linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant

How do you prove that a determinant is a linear transformation using the properties: $T(cx)=cT(x)$ and $T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)$?

For instance, if you had a $3\times3$ matrix: $(1,1,2)+(x,y,z)+(1,2,1)$, how would you prove that taking its determinant with respect to the vector $(x,y,z)$ is a linear transformation?

Comment: It is not. It is linear iff n=1

Answer (score 6):

You can't prove that since the determinant is *not* a linear transformation. For instance, if we are working with $n\times n$ matrices, then $\det(\lambda M)=\lambda^n\det(M)$. If $\det$ was linear, that exponent shouldn't be there, right?!

Comment: if all columns except 1 are held fixed then wouldn't the detA be a linear transformation of that one (vector) variable ?

Comment: @MichaelLee Yes, but your question made no mention to columns.